# How to fix a DevExpress GridView extension's width while keeping its columns' widths resizable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I want to allow the user to resize the GridView extension's columns' but the total width of the grid should be fixed.

I am currently using these settings.

```
settings.Width = 1200;
settings.SettingsBehavior.ColumnResizeMode = ColumnResizeMode.Control;
settings.Settings.HorizontalScrollBarMode = ScrollBarMode.Auto;
```

Though they cause the columns to resize, they also resize the width of the grid when I resize the columns.

Some important things:

a) I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and DevExpress v12.2.10.0

2) My grid has just 2 columns.

Comment: I think you need to set [ColumnResizeMode](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxClassesColumnResizeModeEnumtopic) to `NextColumn`.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Please post it as an answer and I will mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `ColumnResizeMode.NextColumn` in the settings of the `GridView`.

From the [documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxClassesColumnResizeModeEnumtopic):

> Changing a column's width changes the next column's width.